# How to probe programmatically hardware virtualization capability of the CPU?

Tags: delphi, cpu, virtualization

How to check programmatically that the CPU supports **Hardware Assisted Virtualization** ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using JCL? Something like [this function](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help%3aGetCpuInfo) might be useful, but it looks like the docs have not been updated in a while.

Comment: **JclSysInfo.pas** seems to be promissing. I have found within it a bunch of flags related to *Virtual Machine Extension*: VME_FLAG, INTEL_VME, AMD_VME, EAMD_VME, CYRIX_VME, ECYRIX_VME, TRANSMETA_VME and ETRANSMETA_VME. So far, I cannot tell wether they have to do with my post. Need to investigate further.